# 502.3 Error when using IIS Express with dotMemory to try an locate memory issues

Tags: c#, .net, json, iis, dotmemory

When running an IIS Express server in windows 10, I keep getting a **502.3 error** when making a JSON request using python.

The full error is a follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 502.3 - Bad Gateway</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;}
code{margin:0;color:#006600;font-size:1.1em;font-weight:bold;}
.config_source code{font-size:.8em;color:#000000;}
pre{margin:0;font-size:1.4em;word-wrap:break-word;}
ul,ol{margin:10px 0 10px 5px;}
ul.first,ol.first{margin-top:5px;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;word-break:break-all;}
.summary-container fieldset{padding-bottom:5px;margin-top:4px;}
legend.no-expand-all{padding:2px 15px 4px 10px;margin:0 0 0 -12px;}
legend{color:#333333;;margin:4px 0 8px -12px;_margin-top:0px;
font-weight:bold;font-size:1em;}
a:link,a:visited{color:#007EFF;font-weight:bold;}
a:hover{text-decoration:none;}
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;}
h3{font-size:1.4em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#CC0000;}
h4{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 5px 0;
}#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS",Verdana,sans-serif;
 color:#FFF;background-color:#5C87B2;
}#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.summary-container,.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
.content-container p{margin:0 0 10px 0;
}#details-left{width:35%;float:left;margin-right:2%;
}#details-right{width:63%;float:left;overflow:hidden;
}#server_version{width:96%;_height:1px;min-height:1px;margin:0 0 5px 0;padding:11px 2% 8px 2%;color:#FFFFFF;
 background-color:#5A7FA5;border-bottom:1px solid #C1CFDD;border-top:1px solid #4A6C8E;font-weight:normal;
 font-size:1em;color:#FFF;text-align:right;
}#server_version p{margin:5px 0;}
table{margin:4px 0 4px 0;width:100%;border:none;}
td,th{vertical-align:top;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;font-weight:normal;border:none;}
th{width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:2%;font-weight:bold;}
thead th{background-color:#ebebeb;width:25%;
}#details-right th{width:20%;}
table tr.alt td,table tr.alt th{}
.highlight-code{color:#CC0000;font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;}
.clear{clear:both;}
.preferred{padding:0 5px 2px 5px;font-weight:normal;background:#006633;color:#FFF;font-size:.8em;}
-->
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
<div class="content-container">
  <h3>HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway</h3>
  <h4>The operation timed out
</h4>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><h4>Most likely causes:</h4>
  <ul>  <li>The CGI application did not return a valid set of HTTP errors.</li>         <li>A server acting as a proxy or gateway was unable to process the request due to an error in a parent gateway.</li> </ul>
 </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><h4>Things you can try:</h4>
  <ul>  <li>Use DebugDiag to troubleshoot the CGI application.</li>     <li>Determine if a proxy or gateway is responsible for this error.</li> </ul>
 </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><h4>Detailed Error Information:</h4>
  <div id="details-left">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="alt"><th>Module</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;AspNetCoreModuleV2</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Notification</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ExecuteRequestHandler</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><th>Handler</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;aspNetCore</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Error Code</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0x80072ee2</td></tr>

   </table>
  </div>
  <div id="details-right">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr class="alt"><th>Requested URL</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;http://localhost:44366/api/annotations</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Physical Path</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C:\Users\320067977\Documents\Repos\Philips.Pxl.Platform.Annotations\src\Annotations.Web.Api\api\annotations</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><th>Logon Method</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Logon User</th><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Anonymous</td></tr>

   </table>
   <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="content-container">
 <fieldset><h4>More Information:</h4>
  This error occurs when a CGI application does not return a valid set of HTTP headers, or when a proxy or gateway was unable to send the request to a parent gateway. You may need to get a network trace or contact the proxy server administrator, if it is not a CGI problem.
  <p><a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&amp;IIS70Error=502,3,0x80072ee2,17763">View more information &raquo;</a></p>

 </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> This error appears to be related to the use of dotMemory to analyze
>   the use of memory of the website when a large JSON request is made as
>   the 502 error does not occur when the application is run without
>   dotMemory.

Could anyone advise as to a potential source of the issue or if dotMemory has a config option that may correct this error?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with bad gateway error, but just in case. Try to switch off allocations gathering when you start profiling, it slows down a profiling application and could cause problems when timeout is critical.

Comment: It is hard to say what is the root cause of this 502.3 especially this is the first time I see a 502.3 without ARR proxy.  Have you tried to analyze the dump file with debug diagnostic tool? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924